# Retain fragment state in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an activity let's say its name is `MainActivity`, there are three button in that activity,

```
button one launch FragmetA
button two launch FragmetB
button three launch FragmetC
```

when the `MainActivity` launch initially `FragmentA` launch.

Lets say there is a button in `FragmentB` , on that button click a new Activity `SecondActivity`  launch . When I click the backbutton from `SecondActivity`, it backs to `MainActivity` and `FragmentA` launch, what I want is when I will press the back button from `SecondActivity` I want to see `FragmentB`, how can I do this ?

Comment: use startActivityForResult and base on result replace fragment by main activity

Answer (score 1):

Just save which fragment was opened in `onSaveInstanceState`, and show proper fragment in `onCreate`. For instance:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        switch (savedInstanceState.getString("fragment")) {
            case "a":
                //show fragment a
                break;
            case "b":
                //show fragment b
                break;
            ...
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putString("fragment", "a"); // in case if fragment a visible
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> when the MainActivity launch initially FragmentA launch.

How do you launch your fragment from `MainActivity`? Your `Fragment` state should be persisted by the `FragmentManager`, so if you do:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Only launch if Activity is not recreated.
        launchFragmentA();
    }
}
```

You should see `SecondActivity` when returning from `FragmentB`.